# Calculate Maximum Occurrences of Overlapping time in a day for a time period

Tags: google-sheets

I have a hard time figuring out how to get this formula right. I checked every answer here and no one has described a scenario like this:

Picture a "Gantt" chart that displays start and end dates of users. If a user has overlapping times within a day a new row has to be added in the Gantt chart. I am trying to count how many maximum amounts of "rows" or occurrences where there where more than one task per day every user had.

The expected result can also just be 2 for every row of User 1 or 5 for every row of user 2 depending on how easy it would be to achieve this.

[image: Here is some sample data]

---

[image: Here's the visual representation of the data]

Currently, the formula I have in every row of Column D is this, but this just counts the numbers of overlaps:

```
=IF(A2<>"",SUMPRODUCT(($B2<=$c$2:$c)*($c2>=$b$2:$b)*($A2=$A$2:$A))>1,"")
```

Comment: so you want what exactly to add to the overlap count? pls provide some example

Comment: Do you just want to `sumif()+1` for each user?

Comment: @player0 maximum numbers of tasks per users that overlapped for the entire time period

Comment: @Cyril that could work if I can get the sumif() to iterate through the entire list and account for each user. Each user is stored alphabetically, if that helps.